# 150mm bottom bracket? Where to buy this?

Tags: bottom-bracket

Can someone explain why I can't figure out where to find a replacement for this?

Am I misunderstanding the sizing?

Is this a 150mm bb or is that not important?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google the manufacturer and part number information stamped on it. It's a VP BC-63, which yes is a fatbike square taper cartridge BB, 150mm spindle length for 100mm threaded shells.

If you have to replace it with something that's not the same part, you'll want to start by measuring the actual spindle length (tip to tip) as well as any offset. Many fatbike BBs have offset, but it doesn't appear this one does, so you'll want to make sure to get that part right.

Fatbike square taper cranks and bottom brackets are humble parts and not common. It wouldn't be surprising that what you're up against feels like a goose chase.

You might see it listed as 100x150 or the like. This is in line with more normal-looking BB designations such as 68x118, 73x123 etc.

If you can't find a same-length replacement, the next things to look at are whether to change the cranks, whether the chainline and tire clearance situation with the cranks you have could be acceptable with an available spindle length (this would tend to mean going wider since fatbikes usually don't come with chain-tire clearance to spare), or whether to look at putting new bearings into your existing cartridge.

Replacing the bearings on a sealed cartridge unit is usually far more hassle than it's worth, but this is the kind of application where it could make sense. Usually the stuck-together bits are held together by retaining compound, which you can soften up with a heat gun, being careful not to start any (uncontainable) fires since there's still grease inside.

Comment: Thanks very much for this great info